# Horizontal Scroll to display PDF in Swift

Tags: swift, pdf, webview

i have collection view users can download and view the PDF file in web view. My app is landscape so vertical scroll feels weird, so i want to make the scroll horizontal. Is that possible in Web view? or i must use scrollview instead? in swift.

i'm using alamofire download and my destination:

```
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]

                    let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(magazineObject.title).pdf")

                    return fileURL
                }
```

here's my code to view pdf

```
class RedirectMagazineViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var receiveData: NSURL!
var receiveTitle: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("receiveData 2ndVC =>\(receiveData)")
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    self.title = receiveTitle
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(receiveTitle).pdf"
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 11 has Apple solved the problem with PDFKit.

A good intro can be found [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/rendering-pdf-documents-using-pdfkit-9ac4944a6dfb)

```
import PDFKit

@IBOutlet var pdfView: PDFView!

if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
    pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
    pdfView.autoScales = true
    pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
    pdfView.document = pdfDocument
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PDF files are inherently a collection of pages as soon as you do not design pdf file that support horizontal manner you could not horizontal scroll the pdf file Regard less you display pdf in `UIWebView, Chrome, Safari, Preview, FireFox, Windows 8 Reader` etc..`

Comment: I try to add that code before and after load request and still doesn't work

Comment: @Ariel Gemilang - i have tested this code with sample pdf file its work. kindly check if you still get any problem let me know

Comment: i add `webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator  = false
        webView.scalesPageToFit = true
        webView.delegate = self` after `webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)` my scroll is still vertical

Comment: @Ariel Gemilang - by mistake i assumed it as vertical scrolling . wait i will give you correct code

Comment: @Ariel Gemilang - see my answer

Comment: So I can't scroll Horizontal in Webview?

Comment: @Ariel Gemilang - You can scroll Horizonatal but only with respect to the width of your pdf file. or your pdf file are arrange in horizontal manner only.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is very limited in what it allows you to customize when it comes to displaying PDF. Enabling the vertical scroll indicators will not change anything.

The only way to switch to vertical scrolling is to start all the way from scratch at `CGContextDrawPDFPage` - see [Apple's documentation for a start](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html)

There are various [open source](https://github.com/schwa/iOS-PDF-Reader) and [commercial PDF SDK](https://pspdfkit.com/) available that solve this, as it's a very hard problem to even just replicate the features of UIWebView. Text selection alone is really, really hard. I've been working on [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) since 2010, and we're still working on it 7 years later.

[Apple's ZoomingPDFViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) is a good intro if you are willing to invest a few month to build this yourself.